# Non-versioned sign (blue question mark) not displayed on windows 8.1

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

Non-versioned sign (blue question mark) not displayed on windows 8.1

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7.7(64-bit) on windows 8.1(64-bit) .while adding any file or folder Non-versioned sign (blue question mark) is not displayed. all other icon displaying well.

Is there any compatibility issue?

Answer (score 2):

That's a [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotall)

In short: you have too many overlay handlers already in use.